# Reading from file using fstream corrupts data

Tags: c++, file, fstream, corrupt, resource-files

In Visual Studio 2013 using the VC11 compiler i try to implement an automatic build increment, for that reason I try to read the resource-file with the version information with a fstream, but the problem is that half of the loaded content is corrupted  e.g. by chinese characters, after I rewrite it back to the file.
I read the file like this:

```
        mFile.open(mParams.tFilename.c_str(), std::fstream::in);

        if (!mFile.is_open())
        {
                cerr << "ReadFile:Cannot open file!\n";
                return false;
        }

        string line = ""; 
        mFileContent.clear();
        while (getline(mFile, line))
        {
                mFileContent.push_back(line);
        }
```

And write back to the file like this:

```
  mFile.open(mParams.tFilename.c_str(), std::fstream::out  std::fstream::trunc);
  std::ostream_iterator<std::string> output_iterator(mFile, "\n");
            std::copy(mFileContent.begin(), mFileContent.end(), output_iterator);
```

But the content looks like this ( I couldn't use it in SO as a block quote, because then I get the warning (... cannost begin with):
http://pastebin.com/D1J5UfFr

instead of this:
http://pastebin.com/WL6pGX9A

But why exactly is that so? And how can I solve it?

Comment: Open file in binary mode. It seems like you don't want to read text, but binary data.

Comment: I have to read it in text-mode because I change the lines with the version info. Only for demonstration purposes I read the file and write the same back to it, but the effects are the same.

Comment: @mbed_dev "I have to read it in text-mode"  No, you don't.  If that were true, the file as it exists before you modify it with `fstream` could not exist.  There are other ways to read and write file data.